# Create a new column named "birth_year" to extract the year from the "birthdate" column, and format as text

Tags: powerbi, dax

i ant to create a new table in power bi using DAX power query a
in which birthdate like this 1/2/2000 and new data only contain year in it

Answer (score 0):

= MONTH([date] this DAX should help with what u want